# Azure VM - Endpoints do not work

Tags: azure, endpoint, azure-virtual-machine

I have VM with two endpoints 3389 and 80. It have been working fine for about 1 week.

Yesterday I was not able to remote to it, not access its services over port 80. I rebooted it - did not help. I decided to delete and recreated endpoints, and it helped. VM worked for a few hours and then I had the same issue. Again I recreated endpoints.

Looks like this is the Azure issue. Does anyone experienced the same problem? Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem today. Only thing that worked was to recreate ALL the endpoints. My VM was in the West Europe data center.

Answer (score 0):

First, what OS are you using?

Then, if it Linux - it shall be working, might be some issue with the specific VM instance.

If it is Windows, besides the Endpoints, you have to also add local Firewall rules for the ports you want to be accessed from the outside world.

I've never experienced your issue, but I always tune the Firewall of the Windows Machine (specifically for port 80, port 3389 is allowed by default).

In general there shall be no issues, but as we all know this service is still in `Preview` and there might be some issues related to a specific Data Center. So I often suggest to try creating VM in another Data Center if customer is facing issues with VM service. If you try West Europe, go and give a try in North Europe. If you use South-Central US, go and try North US, etc.

Comment: It's Windows. And Firewall of the Windows is configured correct. Thank you for idea of changing data center, I will try it if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try the connection troubleshoot tool. Sometimes it can provide the actual reason why the connection is failing

[Connection Troubleshoot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhcPb.png)